# Finding a positive lower bound of the sequence $\frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, factorial, radicals

I am given a sequence $$\frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}n.$$ Can I show that the sequence is bounded below by a real no. which is greater than 0, by not calculating the limit of it....???thank you

Comment: but the limit of the whole term is 1/e @EugenCovaci , and the sequence is mototone decreasing.....then it must be bounded below by 1/e (>0). But as I do not calculate the limit...so how do I know that?

Comment: So you are talking about $\frac{(n!)^{1/n}}{n}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I properly read the question, you are concerned by $$a_n=\frac{(n!)^{\frac{1}{n}}}{n}$$ So $$\log(a_n)=\frac 1n \log(n!)-\log(n)$$ As usual when working with factorials, [Stirling approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation) is useful. You will in particular find this very nice inequality $$\sqrt{2\pi}n^{n+\frac 12}e^{-n} \leq n! \leq en^{n+\frac 12}e^{-n}$$ which would give you good approximations of upper and lower bounds for $a_n$.

Comment: And how the good approximations are going to be?

Answer (score 1):

By [comparing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Rate_of_growth_and_approximations_for_large_n) $\log n!$ with $\int_1^n \log x \, dx$, we get
$$
n! \ge e\left(\frac ne\right)^n
$$
and so
$$
\frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}n \ge \frac{\sqrt[n]{e}}e \ge \frac1e
$$